# DataTable render table: find string replace

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

I have this php code and I would like to do the same thing with the use of render in datatable:

```
$a1=str_replace("30007","DSL_ID",$row["summary"]);
$a1=str_replace("230003","Unit ID",$a1);
$a1=str_replace("30005","Data Link Sapi ID",$a1);
$a1=str_replace("220005","Lapd & EOC interface identification",$a1);
$a1=str_replace("410001","Chassis ID",$a1);
$a1=str_replace("10004","FAN ID",$a1);
$a1=str_replace("30001","ISUP interface ID",$a1);
$a1=str_replace("30002","CIC",$a1);
$a1=str_replace("1030003","Unit ID",$a1);
$a1=str_replace("30018","MTP3 Link ID",$a1);
$a1=str_replace("30012","IP address",$a1);
$a1=str_replace("30013","IP port",$a1);
$a1=str_replace("30048","Network ID",$a1);
$a1=str_replace("10002","Slot ID",$a1);
$a1=str_replace("1110001","Chassis ID",$a1);
```

The result of this php code for one row is for example:

ET10007_PC40303_SP0|Chassis ID=69, FAN ID=2

The original row ($row["summary"]) is like this:

ET10007_PC40303_SP0|410001=87, 10004=5

can someone help me?

Comment: This looks like php, not jquery. Read [ask] and create a [mcve] please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved like this:

```
columns: [
        { title: "Description",
          render: function (data, type, row) {
            data = data.replace('410001', 'Chassis ID');
            data = data.replace('10004', 'FAN ID');
            return data;
           }
        },

    ]
```